# Python Crash Course (Adding Custom Tooltips)

Tags: python, charts, plotly, hover

Im learning the Python Crash Course book by myself. I'm in Chapter 17 and its about pulling a GitHub repositories from the website and creating a bar chart to show the most rated projects in there.

Actually, I'm in Adding custom Tooltips section and I'm trying to build hover texts. In the Process repository information I added a hover texts list to hold that information and also I created a section called Build hover texts where is the information i want.

When I run the program shows this ValueError:

> ValueError: All arguments should have the same length. The length of argument `hover_name` is 1, whereas the length of  previously-processed arguments ['x', 'y'] is 30

I'm following the steps that the book gave me. I don't know what is the problem plese let me know what is the problem here cause i can't figure it out.

Here is the code:

```
import requests
import plotly.express as px

# Make an API call and check the response.
url = "https://api.github.com/search/repositories"
url += "?q=language:python+sort:stars+stars:>10000"
headers = {"Accept":"application/vnd.github.v3+json"}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print(f"Status code: {r.status_code}")

# Process overall results.
response_dict = r.json()
print(f"Complete results: {not response_dict['incomplete_results']}")

# Process repository information.
repo_dicts = response_dict['items']
repo_names, stars, hover_texts = [],[],[]

for repo_dict in repo_dicts:
    repo_names.append(repo_dict['name'])
    stars.append(repo_dict['stargazers_count'])

# Build hover texts.
owner = repo_dict['owner']['login']
description = repo_dict['description']
hover_text = f"{owner}<br />{description}"
hover_texts.append(hover_text)

# Make visualization.
title = "Most-Starred Python Projects on GitHub"
labels = {'x':'Repository', 'y':'Stars'}
fig = px.bar(x=repo_names, y=stars, title=title, labels=labels, hover_name=hover_texts)
fig.update_layout(title_font_size=28, xaxis_title_font_size=20, yaxis_title_font_size=20)

fig.show()
```

Comment: The block of code after `# Build hover texts` should be indented so it's inside the `for` loop.

Comment: Otherwise you're only adding one hovertext, not one for each item in the plot.

Comment: @Barmar thank you for your answer, that was the solution, i was getting crazy with that